# didRangeBeacons not showing any beacon devices

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ibeacon

I am new to beacon programming.

I searched on SO and got lots of help, but stuck at one point.

as my didRangeBeacons is getting called, but it is always showing null array for beacons.

Here is my code for didDiscoverPeripheral

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:peripheral.identifier.UUIDString];

    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"com.XXXXXX.beacon"];

    self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
}
```

and this is code for didRangeBeacons

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
    foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];
NSString *uuid = foundBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString;
     NSString *major = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.major];
     NSString *minor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.minor];

     NSLog(@"%@",uuid);
     NSLog(@"%@",major);
     NSLog(@"%@",minor);
}
```

this always gives me null values..
whats getting wrong.
Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you're using `peripheral.identifier` as the UUID of the beacon region you're ranging and monitoring for.

It's deceptive, because they both use the same *Version 4 UUID* format, but **Peripheral UUID** and **iBeacon UUID** are two completely different things:

- **Peripheral UUID** identifies a particular BLE device. However, even for the BLE same device, its peripheral UUID will differ from iPhone to iPhone, and might also change after you either the iPhone, or the Bluetooth subsystem gets rebooted.

  You can think of it as an ephemeral identifier that an iPhone assigns to a BLE device so that you can identify it between Core Bluetooth calls *on that iPhone*.

  This is part of the Core Bluetooth subsystem, which is intended for use with any non-iBeacon BLE devices.
- **iBeacon UUID** is just a static value which an iBeacon device broadcasts. It's going to be the same for all iPhones that discover it, because unlikely Peripheral UUID, this is not something that the iPhone assigns, but rather a property of the beacon itself.

  On the iOS side, this is part of the Core Location subsystem, which is intended for use with iBeacon.

In your `CLBeaconRegion`, you need to use the iBeacon UUID of your beacons, not the Peripheral UUID. Consult with the vendor of your beacons on how to discover the iBeacon UUID of your beacons. Most vendors simply assign a pre-defined static value to all the beacons they produce (but you can often change it to your own).

Note that **you need to know the iBeacon UUID upfront** to be able to discover iBeacons with that UUID. There's no way around that.

---

I'm also not exactly sure why you're starting iBeacon ranging/monitoring in response to a Core Bluetooth scan—unless you have a very specific reason, you don't need to do it this way. You can just move out all of your code out of the `didDiscoverPeripheral` method.

Comment: Thanks for information, but client is producing their own BLE devices and to which we have to connect. Somehow I am succeed in detecting BLE and getting to point you mention I am sure now that peripheral UUID and iBeacons UUID is different. As of now our Android team is getting other UUID and me getting different one.
so is there any way to get exact UUID of the device that will be same to all......?

Comment: On iOS, sadly, no, there's no way. Core Bluetooth will only give you the "ephemeral" peripheral UUID, and will filter out the iBeacon UUID; while Core Location requires you to know the iBeacon UUID upfront. Android doesn't have the "peripheral UUID" at all, it just gives you the iBeacon UUID straight away, but without requiring you to know it upfront.

Answer (score 0):

The device is not detecting any beacons.  The line `foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];` is returning Nil, you can see this if you change your code to:

```
{
CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];
if (foundBeacon != Nil) {
   NSString *uuid = foundBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString;
   NSString *major = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.major];
   NSString *minor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.minor];

   NSLog(@"%@",uuid);
   NSLog(@"%@",major);
   NSLog(@"%@",minor);
  }
  else {
    NSLog("No beacons detected");
  }
}
```

It is unclear why it is not detecting beacons, but the most common reason is that the identifiers in the CLBeacon region you use to start ranging do not match what the beacon is transmitting.  It may help to show this setup code.

It is worth noting that the  `didDiscoverPeripheral` code shown is not necessary for detecting beacons and has no role in basic beacon detection.

**UPDATE:  The comment of the questioner below is critical:**

> I am using didDiscoverPeripheral method to find the available BLE devices and to get those UUID and then setting then I am setting startMonitoringForRegion and startRangingBeaconsInRegion. As I am unaware of UUID that is for device

**The above technique will not work, because the UUID returned by `didDiscoverPeripheral` has nothing to do with the beacon ProximityUUID**, even though both UUIDs use the same string format and superficially look similar.  **There is no public API in iOS to get a beacon's ProximityUUID without knowing it in advance.**  See my blog post here for more info: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

Comment: :- I am using didDiscoverPeripheral method to find the available BLE devices and to get those UUID and then setting then I am setting startMonitoringForRegion and startRangingBeaconsInRegion. As I am unaware of UUID that is for device...

Comment: Thanks for this... but it always goes in else loop resulting "NO Beacons detected"

Comment: I see the problem for why you are not detecting beacons.   Please see the edit I added to my answer.